# What does Jesus mean when he said "Night is coming" in John 9:4?

Tags: jesus, crucifixion

**John 9:4 NIV**

> As long as it is day, we must do the works of him who sent me. Night is coming, when no one can work.

He also says in the next verse,

> While I am in the world, I am the light of the world.

What does Jesus mean by the phrase, "Night is coming", followed by the clause, "when no one can work"? Was he alluding to his death on the cross?

Comment: Related: [Night is coming, when no one can work](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/19594/9713)